# Скролл лист в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, прокрутка, ui

Каким образом можно создать вертикально пролистываемый список из кнопок в unity при помощи UI?Количество кнопок всегда разное и зависит от данных,введенных игроком.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.VerticalScrollbar.html

Comment: Собственно насколько я помню при добавлении элементов в скролл рект он ресайзится, автоматом, разве нет?

Comment: возможно,я новичок и много не знаю,смысл в том,что нужен список из большого количества кнопок,и все из сцены не добавить,а как добавить из скрипта я не знаю,вот и спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо создать:

1. `ScrollRect` - сам список.
2. Layout группу. На ваш вкус. В вашем случае это `VerticalLayoutGroup`.
3. Создать связь между Layout группой и `ScrollRect`. Задав в необходимое поле в `ScrollRect` нашу группу (`ScrollRect.content`).
4. Создавать дочерними элементами относительно `Layout` нужные кнопки. `button.transform.SetParent(layout.transform);`

Так же можете поиграться с `LayoutElement`, добавив его к вашей кнопке.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос старый, но может кто выйдет на него по поиску, потому отвечу.

Создаёте стандартный UI/Scroll View через правую кнопку мыши в иерархии/любым иным привычным способом. 
На объект content вешаете компоненты [Vertical Layout Group] и [Content Size Fiter][1]
На корневой объект префаба вешаете [Layout Element]

Дальше вышеназванные компоненты настраиваете и подгоняете согласно своим запросам. Смотря кто чем из них должен управлять.
Прикрепил к компонентам ссылки на их API.

Судя по комментариям, которые я от вас тут увидел, вас вообще интересует возможность добавить объекты в список в процессе игры.

Содержание класса, который будет это делать выглядит примерно так:

```
[SerializeField] 
GameObject _buttonPrefab; 

[SerializeField]
ScrollRect _scrollRect; 


public void CreateButton()
{
    GameObject button = Instantiate(_buttonPrefab, false);
    var component = button.GetComponent<Image>(); 
    component.color = Color.red;

    button.transform.SetParent(_scrollRect.content, false);
}
```

[SerializeField] - отображает поле в редакторе, но оставляет его приватным, что в отличии от модификатора public не нарушает инкапсуляцию класса
Instantiate - создаёт и возвращает копию объекта. есть перегрузки - можете ознакомиться в документации.
После создания объекта, можете делать с ним, что хотите, а после настройки помещаете в дочерние объекты внутрь контента скрул ректа, который автоматически уже включит этот объект в скорлящийся список(Vertical Layout Group) и изменит свой размер(Content Size Fiter)

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой туториал [EN]

https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-scrollbar

Документация

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.VerticalScrollbar.html

Comment: Благодарю,но в видео уроке нет ответа на мой вопрос